# Unexpected tokens on ES6 export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to understand how ES6 export works.

Here are two local files:

*main.html*:

```
<script src="module.js"></script>
<script>
    import {hello} from './module'; // Tried both "module" and "module.js"
    let val = hello();
    alert(val);
</script>
```

*module.js*:

```
export function hello() {
    return 'Hello';
}
```

Expected result: alert with "Hello" text in it. Actual result: errors:

> module.js - line 1:   Unexpected token `export`
>
> main.html - line 3:   Unexpected token `{`

How to make it work?

PS. Tested in Chrome 67.

Comment: I guess that error is due to the lack of browser support :/

Comment: all browser (and versions) cannot support it. it should be transpiled before it can be used; with, for e.g: babel

Comment: You should use a transpiler like babel

Comment: Add `type="module"` to your `<script>` tags

Comment: @JonasW. Tested in Chrome 67. I tend to think that ES6 export works in Chrome, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @DominicTobias Thank you. Yes, after I changed the 1st line, I got another error: about CORS policy. So, I restarted Chrome with [CORS restrictions disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718). But then I got another new error: `module.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of ""`. I haven't fixed this new error for now, [but it seems it doesn't have "nice" workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478). Actually I need this for Chrome extension and probably Chrome extensions have some good way to deal with MIME types.

Comment: Note that I just had a similar experience though the problem was a missing `}`. I can't say I love that the error was ` Unexpected token export` but I guess it makes sense from a certain point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full support of JavaScript modules have been added to Chrome [since version 61](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232). Here's the essential part you apparently missed in the doc:

> Modules must be eventually included in your HTML with **type="module"**,
>   which can appear as an inline or external script tag.

You don't have to use the first script; `import` will direct browser to download the required module. So this should be enough:

```
<script type="module">
    import {hello} from './module.js';
    let val = hello();
    alert(val);
</script>
```

There's a caveat, however: you won't be able to serve modules from filesystem directly in Chrome - you'll need to either set up a 'regular' HTTP server or apply workarounds described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ).