# Error while loading Angular 8 project in webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, mime-types

While loading the file path

`file:///android_asset/mobile-apps/index.html`

in webview its giving an error in console of webview.

This is a `Angular 8` build project added in assets. Earlier it was working.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mobile-apps/index.html")
```

> Error Msg:
>   runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>   polyfills-es2015.ee48165b7784881dd54a.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>   main-es2015.630e9f8943af099641ef.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403528/4360419

Comment: Have a look above