# trying to separate backend and frontend on same domain

Tags: angular, api, .htaccess, docker

I want to have the back-end and front-end of my website separated.
For the front-end i am using Angular.
For the backend i am using Symfony.

To run everything i use Docker from `php:7.1.8-apache`

The back-end does run, and i can access it from `http://localhost:8080/api/`

I have looked in internet for things, and tried a lot of them that would suite me. But it did not work.

I tried to make a .htaccess and set this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ core/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ spa/dist/spa/
```

Docker:
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
 app:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
  image: meeting-rooms-docker
  ports:
   - 8080:80
  volumes:
   - .:/srv/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.8-apache

MAINTAINER Joey

COPY . /srv/app
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/app \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/

    <Directory "/srv/app/">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my file structure:

```
projectFile
- spa (Angular)
- Core (Symfony)
- .docker
.htaccess
```

when i use the command `ng serve` in the spa folder. It shows the right page (the welcome page).
But when i go to the page that is run with docker and is going true the .htaccess it shows this error:
`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`
in the console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ)

Comment: @dahe Not really. It is a empty Angular project (just created a new one and added a route). And it is run with docker, not in the local browser. i have the same issue with firefox, and this does not seem to work for me. But thank you for trying to help :)