# Getting "Failed to load module script..." even though I run my code on a local server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I get `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` after importing `axios` into a javascript file.

Based on: [ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ?rq=1)

I though that all I had to do is to run my code on a server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080/) instead of on the file system (e.g. `file:///C:/Users/...`).

I did that by downloading `http-server` with `npm` and ran everything on the above server--but I still get that error.

**Edit:**

Failed import statement `import axios from './node_modules/axios';`

Comment: Why don't you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server ? It's better!

Comment: No particular reason. After looking for a solution `http-server` was the first thing recommended so I used that. Why is the `local web server` better?

Comment: Can you please show the failed import statement? The first coming to mind is, that the file was not found, and the server responded with 404 page (which is HTML). Have you chceked the network tab on the DevTools?

Comment: @Teemu--I edited the post with that.

Comment: The path is correct? Also I suspect a browser needs a full filename too.

Comment: I've tried other variations for the path but this should be the correct one. What do you mean by browser needing a full filename?

Comment: The module is saved in a .(m)js file, that file name, including the extension.

Comment: Not sure. It is in a `package-lock.json`, `package.json` and in `node_modules` which contains `axios`' code. All are under the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might need `type="module"` on your `script` tag. See: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/