# Web worker as type module fails to load module script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, javascript-import

I have the worker helper in react called `workerBuilder.js`:

```
export function getWorker(worker) {
  const code = worker.toString();
  const blob = new Blob([`(${code})()`]);
  return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), { type: 'module' });
}
```

I then have this `fileUploadWorker.js`:

```
import { uploadFile } from 'utilities/storage.utils';
import { STORAGE_BUCKET_ENUM } from 'models/application/enums/ImageEnums';

export default () => {
  self.onmessage = async (message) => {
    const result = await uploadFile(message.data.file, STORAGE_BUCKET_ENUM.ATTACHMENTS, message.data.filePath);
    if (!result) {
      postMessage('Could not upload');
      return;
    }

    postMessage('File uploaded');
  };
};
```

Now when I try to use it in another function, like this:

```
const instance = getWorker(fileUploadWorker);

instance.postMessage({ file, filePath });
```

I see this error in console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Not sure where the problem lies, but I suspect the imports don't work? Any ideas?

My goal is to create a worker that handles uploading files async so I don't have to wait for it to complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 modules in local files - The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ)

Comment: Not really. I tried that, for example: `import { uploadFile } from 'utilities/storage.utils.ts';` and still the same error

Comment: Browsers can't execute TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to explicitly set the MIME type for your blob ?

```js
export function getWorker(worker) {
  const code = worker.toString();
  const blob = new Blob([`(${code})()`], { type: 'application/javascript' }); // Explicitly set the MIME type
  return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), { type: 'module' });
}
```

This explicitly sets the MIME type of the Blob to 'application/javascript', which should probably resolve the error you're encountering.

Comment: yep, just tried and now it says `ncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: utilities_storage_utils_ts__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined` but its prob as mentioned that i cant import typescript files?

Comment: Yes, by default, web workers don't have built-in support for TypeScript. You'll need to transpile your TypeScript code into JavaScript first.